# Multiple ionic Badges On Tabs Not Working

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to add badges to my tabs in ionic, having one badge works fine using the following code:

```
 <nav class="tabs tabs-icon-bottom tabs-positive">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="showVenue('venue')"><i class="icon ion-waterdrop"></i>Venue</a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="showComments()"><i class="icon ion-ios-chatbubble"></i>Comments</a>

    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="showEvents()"><span class="badge badge-assertive">{{detail.events}}</span><i class="icon ion-calendar"></i> Events</a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="showMap()"><i class="icon ion-android-pin"></i>Map</a>

    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="showOffer()"><i class="icon ion-pizza"></i> Offers</a>
  </nav>
```

However adding one more badge on, seems to not display or messes up the current view, e.g.

Venue
    Comments

```
<a class="tab-item" ng-click="showEvents()"><span class="badge badge-assertive">{{detail.events}}</span><i class="icon ion-calendar"></i> Events</a>
<a class="tab-item" ng-click="showMap()"><i class="icon ion-android-pin"></i>Map</a>

<a class="tab-item" ng-click="showOffer()"><span class="badge badge-assertive">{{detail.events}}</span><i class="icon ion-pizza"></i> Offers</a>
```

I'm I doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working in my current project, the only difference is that my 2 badges bind to 2 different values.

Here you are binding the 2 badges to same property {{detail.events}}, could you try with 2 different values?

Another difference is that I use `<ion-tabs>`  and `<ion-tab>` directives while you're using CSS classes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I am using {{detail.events}} and {{detail.offers}}

Comment: OK then why don't you use the tabs directives? It seems to be the recommended way, no?